# Asking Brainteasers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, allowed-questions

I had recently posted a brainteaser on the site and it was closed. I just joined the site a few days ago and I was just wondering why exactly asking such questions is not appropriate.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4314/challenge-question-guess-the-element

Is it because people would try to exploit the reputation system or something? Would it be possible to introduce such questions on the site because I think it would be a good idea.

PS: I love the concept behind Chemistry SE and I'd be happy to help out in whatever way I can around the site..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly (mind you, I'm being slightly tongue-in-cheek here) , you may want to read [Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Well, generally such things become poll-like. Like I said before, [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is the best place for such fun brainteasers.

SE strives to make its questions and answers useful to visitors in the future. Whereas the answers to your teaser may be useful, the question isn't of the form that can easily be found.

However, with some editing you probably could have made your question into a "normal" one (List the criteria, and show a bit of your own work -- see [How To Ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)).

Comment: Haha... I guess that's what makes Stack Exchange different eh? Anyway, I've posted it up on chat in case anyone is interested.